# Airflow schedule_interval and the active dags run

Tags: airflow

## define the instance for processing the training data

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id,
    start_date = datetime(2019, 11, 14),
    description = 'Reading training logs from the corresponding location',
    default_args = default_args,
    schedule_interval = timedelta(hours=1),
)
```

I have the code like this. So in my opinion, this dag will execute every one hour.
But in the airflow web, I got many run days in Schedule part. The day is executing all the time. 
Especially, in the Tree View part, I could see all the block were filled within one hour!!!
I am confused about the schedule_interval function. Any ideas on how to fix that .

Answer (score 1):

On the **FIRST** DAG run, it will start on the date you define on `start_date`. From that point on, the scheduler creates new DagRuns based on your `schedule_interval` and the corresponding task instances run as your dependencies are met. 
You can read more about it [here](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#why-isn-t-my-task-getting-scheduled) .

Comment: You are right. This is what I am trying to explain. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is the problem coming from the non consistent time setting between the really time and start_date. It the start_date is behind the really time, the system will backfill the past time.